# Asus Vivobook x512da switch from no backlight to backlighted keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard, motherboard

So my family bought me this computer, it was pretty good until i had to use it at night or when the sun is too bright on the computer, the keycaps on the keyboard are transparent so i knew i could make it backlighted, i search on internet and found that there is backlighted keyboard for it, i bought one from aliexpress, i receive a thin layer that was the actual stuff that would make my keyboard backlighted and then a other keyboard that i wouldn't need, so i teardown my computer, put everything in place but nothing, I tried searching again for how to enable it but still nothing, i don't know how to do more for this and hope i didn't spend 40$ on only hope

Answer (score 0):

The only manufacturer that can have a keyboard with a backlight in your case is ASUS.

If ASUS has a keyboard with backlight, ask to purchase it from them. The keyboard will have the ASUS Part number on it to assure it will work.

Third party keyboards with backlights or conversions are most unlikely to work because they are not for your specific machine. The keyboard needs to be the exact fit with the proper ASUS SKU number on it.

(Note:  I have replaced the keyboard with backlight on my X230 machine from an eBay source with the exact FRU number and SKU number and of course it did work).